# New phone registration into old apple ID data

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id

I got a new iPhone 4S and I used it to voice-record an important lecture. I plugged it into my computer and iTunes popped up saying I had to register it.

It showed me two options:

1. Register as a new iphone.
2. Register as "*_*_ iphone" which of course was my old apple id.

I texted myself my audio file. I thought registering the iPhone with my old Apple ID would just format a couple things on the phone like the apps, contacts, and pictures. However, I did not realize it would reset everything including my text messages!

I should've texted this file it to another person too!

Can I unregister my old Apple ID and register my iPhone with option 1 (as a new iPhone)? I desperately would like to retrieve that file ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question I doubt you have any backup, the data will be gone and you cannot recover it.

Texting a voice-file is a pretty weird option IMO, as once it will be sent by the provider it won't be sent again to any device. (You don't receive all your text-messages again on a different phone, do you?)

Comment: The number is same, and texting and calling is fine. So, there is absolutely NO way to re-register as a new iphone as I already registered this through my old apple ID?